# Regex: How to extract a word with a preceding number and exclude numbers and colon after that group

Tags: jquery, regex, string, numbers

Consider the following strings:

```
1 Post 12:34

4 Posts 15:11

Deleted 8:46
```

I need to get the first part with the number and exclude the second timestamps: This is what I've tried, but I get null for "deleted".

```
var poststatus = posts.match(/(^)[\d](?<!^)[\D\:]+/);
```

Comment: something like that `(\d*[^\d]+)` ?

Comment: This might help `(\d+):` to match the minutes or `(.*\d+):` to match everything up to the minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
/(.| )*(?= \d+:\d+)/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/EvDkZr/1

Comment: This works, however I got some extra stuff in my array (the last letter of the words), but that was easy enough to parse out. Thank you!